# PySpark - Get the size of each list in group by

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a massive pyspark dataframe. I need to group by `Person` and then `collect` their `Budget` items into a list, to perform a further calculation. 
As an example,

```python
a = [('Bob', 562,"Food", "12 May 2018"), ('Bob',880,"Food","01 June 2018"), ('Bob',380,'Household'," 16 June 2018"),  ('Sue',85,'Household'," 16 July 2018"), ('Sue',963,'Household'," 16 Sept 2018")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ["Person", "Amount","Budget", "Date"])
```

Group By:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df_grouped = df.groupby('person').agg(F.collect_list("Budget").alias("data"))
```

Schema:

```python
root
 |-- person: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

However, I am getting a memory error when I try to apply a UDF on each person. How can I get the size (in megabytes or gigbabytes) of each list (`data`) for each person?

I have done the following, but I am getting `nulls`

```python
import sys
size_list_udf = F.udf(lambda data: sys.getsizeof(data)/1000, DoubleType())
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumn("size",size_list_udf("data") )
df_grouped.show()
```

Output:

```python
+------+--------------------+----+
|person|                data|size|
+------+--------------------+----+
|   Sue|[Household, House...|null|
|   Bob|[Food, Food, Hous...|null|
+------+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: can't you just get the size by counting the number of char in your array ? That'd be easier than using UDF

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @pault I am using python 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have one minor issue with your code. `sys.getsizeof()` returns the size of an object in bytes as an integer. You're dividing this by the integer value `1000` to get kilobytes. In python 2, this returns an integer. However you defined your `udf` to return a `DoubleType()`. The simple fix is to divide by `1000.0`.

```python
import sys
size_list_udf = f.udf(lambda data: sys.getsizeof(data)/1000.0, DoubleType())
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumn("size",size_list_udf("data") )
df_grouped.show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----------------------+-----+
#|person|data                   |size |
#+------+-----------------------+-----+
#|Sue   |[Household, Household] |0.112|
#|Bob   |[Food, Food, Household]|0.12 |
#+------+-----------------------+-----+
```

I have found that in cases where a `udf` is returning `null`, the culprit is very frequently a type mismatch.